Nuxt content alternative for grouping the document/markdown files based on the Taxonomy terms such as Tags, Categories similar to the Docsy
Previously I was using the Docsy based documentation approach to display the contents from my .md files since I saw that Nuxt support this using the Nuxt content I started migrating the Documentation application from Docsy to Nuxt Content.
I have various Taxonomy  information such as Tags, Categories, Keywords in my Markdown .md files in alignment with the Title, Description. In Docsy I could display them nicely at the top of the Content and clicking on the Tags or Categories would show me all the .md files matching those Tags or Categories or something similar to this on Docsy Documentation. Here you can click on any Tags or Categories below the Title and it will navigate to a page with all the Markdown files having those Tags or Categories.
I see the Nuxt content has the ContentNavigation but I don't see any information about showing the pages based on the Taxonomy items such as Tags, Categories etc in Nuxt content.
Is there any feature similar to this in `Nuxt Content which works out of the box? Or can we build this feature by using some additional library or other workaround?
